# slow AJAX response in rails application

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ajax

I am developing a feature for RoR application. I am getting a slow response from AJAX call I made. I am not sure how to optimize it. I understand that Rails takes a lot of time to process when the query contains inner joins coupled with where clause.

My view is
**_form.html.haml**

```
%body{:onload => "resetDropDown()"}
  %h3 Basic
.form-group{class: ("has-error" if @transfer_request.errors.has_key?("Access requested to"))}
  = f.label "Access requested to", class: "control-label"
  %br
  Biomaterial #{f.check_box :access_biomaterial}
  Data #{f.check_box :access_data}
  = f.error "Access requested to"
= f.input :project_title
= javascript_include_tag "application", "data-turbolinks-track" => true
= f.input :biobank, collection: TransferRequest.biobanks.keys, prompt: 'Select biobank', id: 'biobank', :input_html => { :onclick => "getBiobank()", :class => "stext"}
= f.association :cohort, collection: Cohort.all, prompt: 'Select Cohort', id: 'cohort', :input_html => { :onclick => "popup()", :class => "stext"}
= f.association :recruitment_phase, collection: RecruitmentPhase.all, prompt: 'Select Recruitment Phase', id: 'recruitment_phase_id'
```

My controller
**transfer_request_controller.rb** contains

```
  def phasenames
    @disease_code_id = params[:disease_code_id]
    **@phase_names = Patient.joins('join "patient_phases" on "patient_phases"."patient_id" = "patients"."patient_id" join "recruitment_phases" on "recruitment_phases"."phase_id" = "patient_phases"."phase_id"').where('"patients"."disease_code_id" = ?', @disease_code_id).select('distinct(patients.disease_code_id)**', 'recruitment_phases.phase_name')
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html
      format.js
      format.json { render json: @phase_names}
    end

  end
```

My **routes.rb** contains

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do

  get 'start/index'
  root 'start#index'

  resources :contacts

  get 'transfer_requests/:id/phasenames/:disease_code_id' => "transfer_requests#phasenames"
```

My **app/assets/javascripts/application.js** contains

```
function popup() {
    var s = '<option value="-1">Select Recruitment Phase</option>';
    $("#transfer_request_recruitment_phase_id").html(s);

    var cohort = document.getElementById('transfer_request_cohort_id');
    var cohort_selectedValue = cohort.options[cohort.selectedIndex].text;

    if (cohort_selectedValue != null){
        $.ajax({
            url: "fallas",
            dataType:'json',
            type:'GET',
            data: "{}",

            success: function (data) {
                for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
                    if (cohort_selectedValue == data[i].disease_name.trim()){
                        newCall(data[i]);
                        break
                    }
                }
            }
        });
    }

}

function newCall(data){
    //Start: Very Crucial!!. Dont remove it
    var s = '<option value="-1">Select Recruitment Phase</option>';
    $("#transfer_request_recruitment_phase_id").html(s);
    //End: Very Crucial!!. Dont remove it

    $.ajax({
        url: "phasenames/"+data.disease_code_id,
        dataType:'json',
        type:'GET',
        data: "{}",

        success: function (data) {
            var s = '<option value="-1">Select Recruitment Phase</option>';
            for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
                s += '<option value="' + data[i].disease_code_id + '">' + data[i].phase_name + '</option>';
            }
            $("#transfer_request_recruitment_phase_id").html(s);

        }
    });
}
```

Can anyone help me with leads to optimize the following query shown in the controller above?.

```
@phase_names = Patient.joins('join "patient_phases" on "patient_phases"."patient_id" = "patients"."patient_id" join "recruitment_phases" on "recruitment_phases"."phase_id" = "patient_phases"."phase_id"').where('"patients"."disease_code_id" = ?', @disease_code_id).select('distinct(patients.disease_code_id)', 'recruitment_phases.phase_name')
```

Comment: Have you verified, that the query is slow? Can you run it in a (psql?) shell and reproduce it? If so it's not really a ruby on rails question. It's a SQL question. And you'll need to post your relevant DB schema parts, particularly what indexes you have.

Comment: It is quick in the psql shell. It executed in 38ms. Whereas in the ruby console, I ran the same query it took 64089.1ms. It has to do with rails indeed. But I thank you for asking

Comment: I mean rails console not ruby console. **correction**

Comment: In the development console you can see what part of the response takes how long. What do you see?